# Imprmir el resultado de un consulta AJAX en un input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Normalmente imprimo una respuesta AJAX en un div o span. Mi duda es si puedo hacer que mi resultado se muestre en un input text.

Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form, #foo').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });       
        return false;
    });
});
```

Después de mi success mi resultado está en un div.

¿Puedo cambiar a un input text dentro de un form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tan simple como obtener con jquery el input y hacer un .val(data)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form, #foo').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#miInput').val(data);
            }
        });       
       return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: no tienes que agregar el event.preventDefault(); para evitar que te agarre el click del boton?

Comment: @JackNavaRow buen punto, se debe agregar esa linea

Comment: SI, pero yo simplemente he cojido el codigo del OP y he cambiado la linea que necesitaba. Ahora lo agrego.